# When i started app getting "Unknown keystone list" Error In Keystone 4.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, keystonejs

I have added routes to post-event data.

```
 var keystone = require('keystone');
 var Event = keystone.list('Event');
 module.exports = function (req, res) {
  if (!req.body.name || !req.body.startTime || !req.body.endTime) {
  return res.send({ status: 'incomplete data set' });
 }
var newEvent = new Event.model();
Event.updateItem(newEvent, req.body, function (error) {
res.locals.enquirySubmitted = true;
 if (error) res.locals.saveError = true;
res.render('addEvent');
});
};
```

When I start the app I am getting below error.

if (!result) throw new ReferenceError('Unknown keystone list ' + JSON.stringify(key));
                 ^

ReferenceError: Unknown keystone list "Events"
    at Keystone.list (/Users/rigalpatel/KS_shopingcart/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/list.js:7:21)
    at Object. (/Users/rigalpatel/KS_shopingcart/routes/api/event/post.js:2:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at /Users/rigalpatel/KS_shopingcart/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/importer.js:42:23
    at Array.forEach ()
    at importer (/Users/rigalpatel/KS_shopingcart/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/importer.js:32:26)
    at /Users/rigalpatel/KS_shopingcart/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/importer.js:36:22
    at Array.forEach ()

Would you please provide your feedback. suggestion how to fix above issue.

### Vesrion

Keystone    4.0.0
Node.js 10.9.0
Browser Google Chrome 69.0.3497.100

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code of your model Event

Answer (score 2):

I had this error and realized I was setting my routes before importing my models. Make sure you are importing your models before setting your routes and that your models are registered.

Answer (score 0):

error comes because you have not created any Model with name **Event**

Comment: If you have anything to say in short consider adding it as a comment.